# Facebook Messanger App callback doesn't call my app

Tags: facebook, chatbot

I created chatbot for Facebook. I tested in on one fanpage, got business and api permissions verfications from Facebook and I wanted to add the bot to more fanpages. I did it as before, I setted all Webhooks like messages, message_echoes but Facebook doesn't call my app. I'm checking it in debuging tool that shows network traffic to my server.

I tried to remove and add callback, fanpages, but nothing gets change.

The first fanpage still works all fine, but others don't call my bot on any message. Why?

Answer (score 0):

assume you link your app to first fanpage with oauth dialog like this before.

oauth dialog : (See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/overview/authorization)

```
https://www.facebook.com/v12.0/dialog/oauth
  ?client_id=<YOUR_APP_ID>
  &redirect_uri=<YOUR_URL>
  &scope=pages_messaging
```

when linking another fanpage with oauth dialog,
should click that edit settings button:
[image: edit setting button]

choose another fanpage:
[image: choose another fanpage]

now you receive webhooks from other fanpages.

Comment: No, it's added and webhooks are set for those new pages. Although "message" is selected for every page I don't receive callback request.

I reported bug and my app settings had been verified and everything is fine, but still waiting for solution. 
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2922810121364802/

Comment: if app is [in development] mode, only fanpage owner receives webhook

Comment: It is not in development, I don't get webhook as owner.

Answer (score 0):

So, problem was in my code. I was checking if request was sent using Symfony profiler. The problem was, it didn't save request if the process was stopped. And it was. I had "die" in some trycatch...